En SQL como puedo agrupar los recursos por horas del TIMESTAMP de UNA consulta entre dos tablas
Tengo el siguiente codigo, me muestra el valor de SUB_NAME pero necesito algo  asi.
CELDA01  7:00 a 8:00 20
CELDA02  7:00 a 8:00 12
CELDA03  7:00 a 8:00 24

SELECT convert(datetime, P.[TIMESTAMP]) as [DATE], SUM(P.[QTY]) as [TOTAL_QTY], SR.SUB_NAME, SR.ID
FROM [MES].[MES].[TBL_PRODUCTION] P 
inner join [MES].[MES].[TBL_SUBRESOURCE] SR on SR.ID = P.SUBRESOURCE_ID
where P.TIMESTAMP between '2024-04-22 07:00:00.000' and '2024-04-22 16:30:00.000' --and P.SUBRESOURCE_ID ='1'''
GROUP BY convert(datetime, P.[TIMESTAMP]),SR.SUB_NAME, SR.ID
order by SUB_NAME asc;



Hola Christian, ¿que motor de BD estas usando?

Buenos dias Marcos, es SQL Server

Puedes valerte de:

la función datepart() para obtener la hora de los registros. Tomando en cuenta que todos los registros entre las 7 y las 8 AM (en realidad entre las 7:00:00.000 y las 7:59:59.999, devolverán la hora 7.
la cláusula group by para agrupar por los campos sub_name y la hora obtenida en el paso anterior
la función de agregación sum() para sumar el campo total_qty para todos los registros de cada grupo.
la función format() para darle formato de dos dígitos a la hora obtenida en el primer paso

Tomando tus datos de ejemplo, con la siguiente consulta:
with
Tabla as (
select *
  from (values 
          (cast('20240422 07:49:56.540' as datetime), 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:51:11.777', 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:51:18.873', 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:53:42.850', 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:55:11.957', 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:59:26.627', 1, 'CELDA 03', 46)
        , ('20240422 07:26:30.980', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 26)
        , ('20240422 07:28:19.617', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 26)
        , ('20240422 07:30:34.383', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 26)
        , ('20240422 07:31:58.020', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 26)
        , ('20240422 07:53:37.897', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 26)
        , ('20240422 07:38:41.587', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 20)
        , ('20240422 07:40:11.590', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 20)
        , ('20240422 07:41:36.470', 1, 'CELL 01 - RAIL RH', 20)
       ) q1 ([DATE], TOTAL_QTY, SUB_NAME, ID)
)
select   SUB_NAME
       , format(datepart(hour, [date]), 'D2') + ':00:00 a ' + format(datepart(hour, [date]) + 1, 'D2') + ':00:00' rango
       , SUM(total_qty) total_qty
  from Tabla
 group by SUB_NAME, DATEPART(hour, [date]);

Obtengo el resultado:
SUB_NAME          rango                total_qty
----------------- -------------------- ---------
CELDA 03          07:00:00 a 08:00:00  6
CELL 01 - RAIL RH 07:00:00 a 08:00:00  8

(2 rows affected)

